# How to enable site localization for Orchard Core

Tags: localization, orchardcms

I'm currently evaluating Orchard Core and I'm trying to enable a multi-lingual blog site. I'm able to activate some of the localization features, but it's not working when publishing the site. Here's what I've try:

- Create a new Orchard Core Site, with the Blog Theme recipe
- Activate the 4 Localization features in the  Configuration
- Add a new language (I'm adding FR) under Configuration/Settings/Cultures)
- I'm adding the Localization to the Blog and Blog Post Content Type (Content/Content Definition/Content Type)
- I go back to the auto-generated blog post, re-publish to activate the localization
- Add a FR content for the same blog post
- I now have both version of the same Blog Post in both language
- Go back to the blog, I see the 2 blog post as they are not linked.

I have the feeling that I'm missing a step or two, anybody ran into this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no feature yet that will filter the List items with the current culture.

Comment: Merci beaucoup @AntoineGriffard, do you know if it's going to be on the first release?

Comment: Instead, you'd rather create two blogs, 1 En and 1 Fr because their urls should be different.